# Entity Framework Order by descending by row field in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to write a EF query which does order by ascending or descending based on condition. Following is the my pseudo code:

```
  var result= q.OrderByDescending(x => x.StatusId == 3)
                    then if( x.StatusId == 3) 
                          then order by x.ReserveDate
                     else
                          then order by descending x.LastUpdateDate
```

How can i do this?

Comment: follow the given link it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643383/order-by-descending-based-on-condition

Comment: `var query=q.OrderByDescending(...); if (..) query=query.ThenBy(...); else query = query.ThenByDescending(...); result=query.ToList();` or something like that.

Comment: doesn't make sense to me you are comparing result set column value to 3 and doing ordering. Instead you should apply condition before querying and then order the result set. if x=3 query should return order by ReserveDate else order by Last Update Date desc.

Comment: Ignore my comment. I missed the fact that your if statement needs the status if the record itself. In that case I agree that it kind of doesn't make sense

Comment: What's the difference with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410923/order-by-descending-by-row-field-in-query)?

Comment: @ivan-stoev Previous question marked as duplicate and unmarked after this question.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this in a single `OrderBy`, for example:

```
var results = q.OrderByDescending(x => 
    x.StatusId == 3 ? x.ReserveDate : x.LastUpdateDate)
```

Comment: one of orders is asc and next is desc

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45413080/edit) your question and provide example data and expected output.